# Gradle error while building the application

Tags: java, android, kotlin, module

Have first module and second module (Phone and Tables Module)

gradle one (main)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.unique.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
....

 implementation project(":network")
.....
```

gradle second

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.io.network"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
...
```

While building catch error "Dependent features configured but no package ID was set." Why?? cannot understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know it is quite late for the answer but it might help others.

If you are let's say adding the Second module to the First module here,
you should in Second gradle

1- change `com.android.application` to `com.android.library`

2- comment or remove `applicationId`

3- provide package information either in the manifest file or use `namespace 'com.io.network'` inside the android tag. This will be useful incase you are using providers, broadcast receivers .

Answer (score 0):

I think in second gradle you should change `com.android.application` to `com.android.library`

Comment: then error "Library projects cannot set applicationId. applicationId is set to 'com.io.network' in default config."

Comment: As I can understand the second gradle is a gradle file of module?

Comment: In that case just remove `applicationId` line

Comment: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@theme value=(@style/AppTheme) from AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-40
 is also present at [:network] AndroidManifest.xml:17:9-51 value=(@style/Theme.MyApplication).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-21:19 to override

Comment: You not need to add theme in AndroidManifest file, you can remove it or add `tools:replace="android:theme"` in Manifest <application/> tag

Comment: again  "Library projects cannot set applicationId. applicationId is set to 'com.io.network' in default config."

Comment: ApplicationId in Library Projects

You cannot use applicationId to customize the package of a library project. The package name has to be fixed in library projects (and specified as packageName in the manifest). The Gradle plugin did not enforce this restriction earlier.

Comment: defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.io.network"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner". Remove this line `applicationId "com.io.network"`